# Return specific items with a relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I created a relationship in my 'Event' model called 'Type'.

```
public function type()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('Types');
}
```

In my 'Types' database, I have several elements. My relationship returns them all, and I would like to know if it was not possible, directly in the relation, to indicate that I only want the types with the column "parent_id" 1.

Thank you very much

Comment: plz share your database structure and more information.. this is less info

Comment: return $this->belongsTo('Types')->where('parent_id', 1);

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add a `where` clause to your relationship. You can do this right in the definition. I guess this isn't very clear in the [laravel 5.5 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships).

Another note, if your model is called "Type" as you stated in the question, then your relationship should use this name as well:

```
public function type()
{
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Type')->where('types.parent_id', 1);
}
```

... or with a namespace...

```
use App\Type;
...
public function type()
{
      return $this->belongsTo(Type::class)->where('types.parent_id', 1);
}
```